# How do I create a string array with switched pairs?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I switch pairs? for ex i have String [] array = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}; and I'm trying to pair and switch their orders like this array {B,A,D,C,F,E,H,G,J,I};

Comment: Do you know how to swap content of two variables? Lets say you have `String a = "foo"; String b = "bar";`, how would you swap their content?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over every pair of adjacent elements (by incrementing the index by 2 each time), then swap them.

```java
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < array.length; i += 2) {
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = temp;
}
```

Alternatively:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    var temp = array[2 * i];
    array[2 * i] = array[2 * i + 1];
    array[2 * i + 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `i < array.length-1`.  Not certain if it compiles differently or not.  The results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stream to achieve that.

```
String[] switched1 = IntStream.range(0, array.length / 2)
    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(i * 2 + 1, i * 2))
    .mapToObj(i -> array[i])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

or

```
String[] switched2 = IntStream.range(0, array.length / 2)
    .mapToObj(i -> 2 * i)
    .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(array[i + 1], array[i]))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. This has the advantage that if there are an odd number of values, it won't throw an exception.  As the loop iterates, it simply swaps adjacent values.

```
String [] array = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i+=2) {
    String save = array[i-1];
    array[i-1] = array[i];
    array[i] = save;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

prints

```
[B, A, D, C, F, E, H, G, J, I]
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch between pairs you can traverse a string and swap adjacent characters and then move to the next of next characters (basically skip the immediate char) and make sure that while performing [i+1] make sure that index doesn't get out of bound

here I'm providing Java code for it  :)

```
    String [] array = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};

    for (int i=0; i< array.length-1; i+=2) {
        String temp=array[i];  //store the current string in temp variable
        array[i]=array[i+1];
        array[i+1]=temp;
    }
```